# Delete customer with total order less than 2 in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, customer

Currently i'm using Magento 2.3.4, i want to run a single mysql query to delete customer with order less then 2 where order date is less then 2018-01-01, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you want to run this query from database (plain sql) or you need an adminside user interface for that?

Comment: I'm gonna run it using Magento 2 raw query function